# Reading textfile parsing rows into a Datatable

Tags: c#, datatable

I want to read a text file and parse each row into a datable.

The way I'd like the data stored in datatable is with the type for each column set as well i.e.
int, varchar, date etc.

```
DataTable data = new DataTable();
data.Columns.Add("code", typeof(int));
data.Columns.Add("description", typeof(string));
data.Columns.Add("value", typeof(decimal));
```

but then when I am reading the textfile with columns tab delimited, how could I ensure the correct columns in the text file go into the right columns in the datatable.

Because my ultimate aim is to get this datatable into a sql server table with the same columns and types using sqlbulkcopy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't  reinvent the wheel, use an available CSV-parser like [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9258/A-Fast-CSV-Reader).

```
DataTable data = new DataTable("CSV");
var fileInfo = new System.IO.FileInfo("Path");
using (var reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(fileInfo.FullName, Encoding.Default))
{
    // use  reader.ReadLine(); to skip all lines but header+data
    Char quotingCharacter = '\0';//'"';
    Char escapeCharacter = quotingCharacter;
    using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, true, '\t', quotingCharacter, escapeCharacter, '\0', ValueTrimmingOptions.All))
    {
        csv.MissingFieldAction = MissingFieldAction.ParseError;
        csv.DefaultParseErrorAction = ParseErrorAction.RaiseEvent;
        //csv.ParseError += csv_ParseError;
        csv.SkipEmptyLines = true;
        // load into DataTable
        data.Load(csv, LoadOption.OverwriteChanges, csvTable_FillError);
    }
}
```

Comment: Will this store the right type of data for each column in datatable. Because the aim is to import this datatable into sql using sqlbulkcopy

Comment: @StevieB: that part wasn't clear to me, how do you determine the type?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to ensure that the columns in the file are always in the correct order. Or if the file could include a header, you can read the file into a list of dictionary rows where the key is the header name/datatable column name.

Reading the file would then be a case of building a list of lines, that can be split on the tab character.